# how do i set the transparency of say the firefox window title in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, transparency

How would I go about setting the transparency of the window bar of each window in ubuntu 12.10. I have tried using compiz config, any ideas? Apologies for noobism.

Answer (score 0):

Open dconf editor, navigate to org > compiz > gwd > and change metacity-theme-active-opacity and metacity-theme-inactive-opacity as you like. 1 is fully opaque.